# JavaScript Module Exports Pattern From One File

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Folder structure:

```
├── app
├── index.js (start point in Webpack)
├── component
│   ├── Home──Home.js
|   ├──index.js
│
```

component/Home/Home.js has my class written like -  `export class Home extends React.Component {}`

component/index.js i had exported like - `export {Home} from './Home/Home'`

and I am Importing in index.js (starting point) `import {Home} from './components'`

Its working for me and the changes I want which is not working

1. In component/Home/Home.js want to export like export default class Home extends React.Component {}
2. In component/index.js i want to  export like export Home from './Home/Home'
3. I want to import in index.js starting point import Home from './components'

Comment: import Home from './components' in index.js -should not be working. It should be `import {Home} from './components`

Comment: please confirm :)

Comment: Its not working but another problem is when I write export default in class then It was giving error

Comment: does this pattern have a name?

Answer (score 0):

in Home

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {}
```

in component/index.js

```
export * from './Home/Home'
```

in index

```
import Home from './components'
```

Comment: Tried but Not Working

Comment: giving Error 
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Answer (score 0):

Imports and exports are independent on file structure, however, you, of course, need to know the file structure because of paths in imports.

> In `component/Home/Home.js` want to export like export default class
>   `Home` extends `React.Component {}`

You can export default class with a keyword default:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
   // your code
}
```

If this for any reason doesn't work for you, you can still do this:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
   // your code
}

export default Home;
```

> In `component/index.js` I want to export like export `Home` from
>   `./Home/Home`

It's hard to say if I don't see a code. I would expect there is also some Home class/function which you would like to export as default, then you can do this (or again the solution above):

```
export default const Home = () => {
   // your code
};
```

Or, again:

```
const Home = () => {
   // your code
};

export default Home;
```

> I want to import in `index.js` starting point import Home from
>   `./components`.

Because of having default exports now, you can do that with this (you can always omit `index.js` from path when importing):

```
import Home from './components';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Home.js:

`export class Home extends Component{ /* your code */ }`

in index.js:

`export { * as default } from './Home/Home'`

in main file:

`import Home from './components'`

Note: In my knowledge all the three conditions you put cannot be met. Moreover, if you export Home as default from index then what about other components?

Answer (score 0):

In order to export all the components you can use the following pattern in `index.js`

```
export Home from './Home'
```

In order for this to work you need to use `babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions` as this is not a current part of the ES specification.